# How to upload a file in ngx dropzone in angular

Tags: angular

Im using ngx-dropzone in angular 8. I don't know how can I upload a file instead of array.

html

```
<div class="custom-dropzone" ngx-dropzone [accept]="'image/*'" (change)="onSelect($event)">
<ngx-dropzone-label>
    <div>
        <h2>My custom dropzone</h2>
    </div>
</ngx-dropzone-label>
<ngx-dropzone-image-preview ngProjectAs="ngx-dropzone-preview" *ngFor="let f of files" [file]="f" [removable]="true" (removed)="onRemove(f)">
    <ngx-dropzone-label>{{ f.name }} ({{ f.type }})</ngx-dropzone-label>
</ngx-dropzone-image-preview>
```

ts

```
  files: File[] = [];

onSelect(event) {
    console.log(event);
    this.files.push(...event.addedFiles);
}

onRemove(event) {
    console.log(event);
    this.files.splice(this.files.indexOf(event), 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should have one way to achieve this. The ngx-dropzone npm module provide as a
input of **multiple** [multiple] attribute but the one drawback of this module is they allow their files in array only. So, we need to remove the added files each time new file is uploaded.

**[multiple]: Allow the selection of multiple files at once. Defaults to true.**

**HTML**

```
 <ngx-dropzone (change)="onSelect($event)">
  <ngx-dropzone-label>Drop it, baby!</ngx-dropzone-label>
  <ngx-dropzone-preview *ngFor="let f of files" [multiple]='false' [removable]="true" (removed)="onRemove(f)" >
      <ngx-dropzone-label>{{ f.name }} ({{ f.type }})</ngx-dropzone-label>
  </ngx-dropzone-preview>
</ngx-dropzone>
```

**Typescript**

```
 
onSelect(event) {
  console.log(event);
  if(this.files && this.files.length >=2) {
    this.onRemove(this.files[0]);
  }
  this.files.push(...event.addedFiles);
}
 
onRemove(event) {
  console.log(event);
  this.files.splice(this.files.indexOf(event), 1);
}
```